# at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)

Tags: android, string

01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jhengweipan.travelofdongshan/com.jhengweipan.travelofdongshan.fuyuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.jhengweipan.travelofdongshan.fuyuActivity.(fuyuActivity.java:18)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1025)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-02 22:54:39.409: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    ... 11 more
01-02 22:54:39.419: E/dalvikvm(11507): 11507 :: IS_UNIFIED_ARM_PROCESS=FALSE, debugFlags = 3

---

```
public class fuyuActivity extends Activity {
private String map =getResources().getString(R.string.watch_map);
private  Object[]listitem={
        map,         WelcomeActivity.class,
        "2",     HeadActivity.class,


};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_fu_yu);
        String[] list = new String[listitem.length/2];
            for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++){
                    list[i]=(String)listitem[i*2];
                }
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

        ListView listview =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(fuyuActivity.this,(Class<?>)listitem[position*2+1]);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }





}
```

Want multiple language, but has been an error, please! Help me solve problems, getResourse.getString (R.string ..) This method is wrong it? Request guru taught me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `getResources().getString(R.string.watch_map)` to be called only after you have called `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in your activity. It is not safe to call most inherited methods from `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()` has been called.

Comment: Would it be feasible/advisable to do something like `MyApp.getApplicationContext().getString(...)` to set that field value?

Comment: @stkent: I would not assume that the `Application` instance is ready by the time the activity class is loaded.

Comment: @jhengweipan: I am sorry, but I do not understand that question. You cannot call `getResources()` on your `Activity` until your `onCreate()` method.